# can classes be too big?

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm planning on adding Steam-like achievement to my gaming site. The calculations will be handled by scheduled cron, with the results stored in a typical MySQL database. For convenience's sake I was considering just dumping all the various calculation methods into one giant `STATS` class. These are methods that would never be called on by any other aspects of the site, only for this particular achievements cron.

Do I need to worry about this class growing too large? It's about 2k LOC now, but there's no reason it couldn't expand to 10k, or 50k, over time...

This is on shared hosting btw, so memory constraints do exist to some degree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, classes can definitely grow too big.**

When that happens, it is usually a sign of misplaced responsibilities. Classes that do too much are an [AntiPattern called The Blob aka God class](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/the-blob). Those classes violate the [Single Responsibiliy Principle](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and will have a negative impact on coupling and cohesion. That in turn will make your application less reusable and harder to extend and maintain.

To divide Responsibilities properly, consider which data you can logically group together and then make that into a separate object. The same is true for overlongy long methods. Divide them. If you find that a particular subroutine is taking a lot of space in an object, see if you can promote that code to a Strategy encapsulating that algorithm.

In your specific case, it sounds like you could benefit from a Command Pattern, e.g. have one StatsCommander that uses many StatCommands (which are Strategies). That keeps the logic required to get the various stats cleanly separated from each other. When you need to add a new Stat, just add a new Strategy/Command.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a class, you ask yourself "Is this function required as an instance? Or as a global function", This is best described by an example:

```
class House {

    private $door;
    private $window;
    private static $adverb;

    public function __construct(Door $door, Window $window) {
        $this->door = $door;
        $this->window = $window;
    }

    public function placeNewDoor($door) {
        $this->door = $door;
    }
    public function placeNewWindow() {
        $this->window = $window;
    }

    public static function advertiseNeighborhood() {
        echo "Advertisment! " . self::$adverb;
    }

}
```

There would be many houses, each would probably have a `Door` and a `Window`. So each of these get an instance method/property. However, you only advertise your `Neighborhood` once (not per house), so that function is static and will be accessed by `House::advertiseNeighborhood`.

Why did I post this example? If there's a function which doesn't required being instantiated, they should remain `static`. It will prevent memory leaking when instantiating multiple objects.

As for your actual question, it's perfectly acceptable to have a very large class, just make sure you don't overuse your memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that the class would grow too large?

And if you think that multiple instance of the same class could used, you can either make all those methods as `static` (So all the functions will have only one instance.)

Or create only one instance of it and let others access the same instance by using `&` before the original instance.

Or you can consider using a `Singleton Pattern`.

**EDIT**

You can consider creating small classes, and making them members of your now big class.

This will keep your code organized and classes divided accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that. If I did think that, I would have titled this question *"classes can grow too big, can't they?"*.

Answer (score 0):

By Creating a Class bigger you only have drawback of leaking memory as most of the functions will not used and will remain sit in the memory till object exist, but the point that if you are creating very few objects like Singleton than it is perfect.

A very good fact is that no mater how many function do you have in a class your execution of single function will take same time as declaring a single function in a class and use it.

What I would suggest you to implement inheritance between classes, code organization mater too, Make a OOD for it. So, you would take less time to modify and managing the code. Take the advantage of encapsulation and polymorphism :)